# Key value observing exposureDuration

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing, avcapturedevice

I'm building a camera app, and I'm trying to expose the current exposure duration to the user. Since this value constantly changes until manually set, I need to use kvo to stream the values to the user. I've successfully done this with the `ISO`, and can observe changes to the `exposureDuration`, but cannot coerce the new value to a `CMTime` object (which is what exposureDuration is). Below is the code I'm using to try and accomplish this:

```
override init() {
  super.init()

  captureDevice = self.selectCamera()

  captureDevice?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "ISO", options: .New, context: &isoContext)
  captureDevice?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "exposureDuration", options: .New, context: &shutterContext)
}

deinit {
  captureDevice?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "ISO")
  captureDevice?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "exposureDuration")
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
  let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]

  if context == &isoContext {
    store.iso.value = newValue as! Float
  } else if context == &shutterContext {
    // The app crashes at this line.
    // Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100091670)
    // newValue is "AnyObject" in the debug area
    store.shutterSpeed.value = newValue as! CMTime
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a legitimate bug that I need to file with apple?

Comment: How did you do it for ISO?

Comment: @Nil You can see it in the example, but regular KVO works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

exposureDuration's newValue is not CMTime, but NSValue.
This is fixed code(swift3).

```
store.shutterSpeed.value = (newValue as! NSValue).timeValue
```